# How to run codes in parallel with a while-loop from Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, while-loop

I would need your help to structure a data analysis script on python that I’m trying to write.

I build a script which run a `while True` loop to retrieve incoming data from a device (through `request`) and appending them into a csv file.

My idea is to create a Tkinter interface where a user can input the IP address, start and stop the data streaming, preview the csv file on a tkinter treeview continuously updated, and perform other things such as create curves automatically upated from data stream with matplotlib.

But I don’t really know what the most efficient way of coding would be. Should I call different python scripts from tkinter or only one script and manage things running in parallel with “multiprocessing”? If having multiple scripts is the best structure for this case, how the scripts can interact back in forth between them?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Baptiste

Some more detail with the draft of my code below:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import csv
import pandas as pd

def init_csv () :
    # building the csv file where will be written the incoming datas

def clear_data():
    # clear all data from both tkinker treeview and csv file
    tv1.delete(*tv1.get_children())
    init_csv()
     
def stream_data():
    # once tkinter "Start Stream" button is clicked:
    # start script ('while True' loop) which will receive incoming data and append to .csv

def stop_stream():
    # once tkinter "Stop Stream" button is clicked:
    # stop script ('while True' loop)

def curve():
    # if tkinter "show curves" button is clicked:
    # show curve continously updating with matplotlib, while data are appended the csv file

# Still need to create a function to update the tkinter treeview automaticaly?

csv_path = 'C:/Users/b/Desktop/testfile.csv'
init_csv()

# Bellow is my Tkinter interface
```

Comment: Do they really need to happen in parallel? Could you not just use the tkinter `.after` method to schedule a function to be called periodically to get the data and update the charts?

Comment: I guess they do: if I'm starting the streaming in a function, the `while True` loop will append my csv file with upcoming data from my external device, and I will not be able to start another function to do something else by clicking on another tkinter button, correct?

Comment: `while` loop is going to freeze your GUI anyways, why not just use `after()` and try `threading` here?

Comment: I looked and learn how threads are working and it worked indeed!. However, seems like `threads` can only be started once, therefore, it could be difficult to start and stop streaming multiple time isn't it?